# JavaFX imageview actions

Tags: javafx, imageview

I'm trying to build a replica of MineSweeper, to do this I'm trying to setup some premade images (100x100 pixels made in Photoshop) into an imageview and then when clicked hiding it (to reveal the number below). Without much complexity -- Just the image going visible and invisible I am finding a lot of issues and difficulties.

It is likely due to a complete lack of knowledge on Javafx in general but I even following tutorials to the t I am still unable to implement this feature. I will attach to this my Main.Java code, my `sample.fxml` code (although it's not called anymore), and then the image I'm trying to hide when clicked.

I have done a lot of research on this (past couple of days) and haven't found anything that solves my problems.

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    ImageView button;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("MineSweeper XP");
        button = new ImageView();

        button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>)(){

            public void handle(MouseEvent event){

            }
        }

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout,1000, 1000);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="button" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="100.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../textures/Button_Custom.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[The "Button" that will be used for all the MineSweeper keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3NQ4.png)

My singular goal at this given moment is to create a window of any size where I can put the button anywhere and then when the user clicks that button it disappears.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `visible` property of  the clicked `ImageView` to `false`? If you have, why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: The code you posted makes no sense. You have `FXML` and no `Controller`. The code with your `Main` doesn't load `FXML` or do anything. It just has an empty button handler.

Comment: my earlier code called the .fxml function but I removed that part in order to try and create a button handler

Comment: dont use a ImageView as a button-like control - instead, use a Button with an ImageView as graphic and change that on action

Comment: @kleopatra I find nothing wrong with using an ImageView as a button-like control, personally. The styling is really the only difference and if all you want is an image that disappears when you click it, using a Button is unnecessary...

Comment: no, styling is not the only difference ;) A button is .. a button, that is meant to be interacted with and has api to interact with, there is no reason to re-invent that api just to show (or not) an image.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create your own `ImageView` that holds the code for mouse clicks within.

Here's a sample `TileButton` class:

```
class TileButton extends ImageView {

    public TileButton() {

        // Set parameters for the image
        Image graphic = new Image("minesweeper/tile.png");
        setImage(graphic);
        setFitWidth(24);
        setFitHeight(24);

        // When this button is click, set its visibility to false.
        setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            setVisible(false);
        });
    }
}
```

Using this custom class, all the logic for the "button" is contained within the `TileButton` itself.

Now, you can populate your mine field with a `GridPane` of `StackPane` containers in each cell. The `StackPane` allows you to stack nodes on top of each other. So, place a `Label` with the number you want into each `StackPane` and then add your new `TileButton` on top of it.

Below is a complete sample application to demonstrate. Note, I am not implementing any of the actual game logic here, just providing a sample you can copy/paste and see in action. I also have not spent any time formatting and styling the `ImageView`, but your could use CSS to make it act like a standard button as well.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // GridPane to hold the cells
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        gridPane.setHgap(2);
        gridPane.setVgap(2);

        // Populate the Gridpane with a 10x10 grid
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

                // Add a new StackPane for each grid cell. The Stackpane will hold a number and the
                // TileButton. When the TileButton is clicked, it disappears, revealing the number below
                StackPane pane = new StackPane();
                pane.getChildren().add(new Label(String.valueOf(number)));
                pane.getChildren().add(new TileButton());

                gridPane.add(pane, j, i);

                // Just increment our sample number
                number++;

            }
        }

        root.getChildren().add(gridPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class TileButton extends ImageView {

    public TileButton() {

        // Set parameters for the image
        Image graphic = new Image("minesweeper/tile.png");
        setImage(graphic);
        setFitWidth(24);
        setFitHeight(24);

        // When this button is click, set its visibility to false.
        setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            setVisible(false);
        });
    }
}
```

The above sample application produces this:

[image: Screenshot]

> **Note** I am not using `FXML` for this as creating a grid of multiple custom objects is much simpler in Java than FXML.

---

Per *kleopatra's suggestion*, this can be accomplished using a custom `Button` instead. With the new `TileButton` class below, you can add the buttons in our loop using `gridPane.add(new TileButton(String.valueOf(number)), j, i);`:

```
class TileButton extends Button {

    public TileButton(String text) {

        // Set the button's size
        setPrefSize(24,24);
        setStyle("-fx-padding: 0");

        // Set the graphic to our tile.png image
        setGraphic(new ImageView("sample/done/minesweeper/tile.png"){{
            setFitWidth(24);
            setFitHeight(24);
        }});

        // Set the button to display only our graphic initially
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        // Set the action to remove the graphic when the button is clicked
        setOnAction(event -> {
            setGraphic(new Label(text));
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra The question was specific  about using an ImageView. This could easily use a Button with CSS styling to remove the padding, but that isn't what the OP asked.

Comment: that's because s/he's a beginner and doesn't yet know which controls to use - you know better ;)

Comment: @kleopatra - I've updated my answer to include a custom `Button` option for your critique. :P

Comment: better - but no reason to extend Button. Simply configure it :)